# How to I bypass the login page on Rstudio?

Tags: docker, rstudio, centos7, rstudio-server

I am trying to bypass the login page on RStudio as we are running it in a Docker container and this step is not necessary as we authenticate before we let users launch the container.

I am using the Rocker implementation of RStudio for Docker.  We are running on Centos7.

I'm fairly new to SO, so please let me know what information would be helpful for answering the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

When you start rserver, add the flag --auth-none=1, so my final CMD in my Dockerfile looked like:

```
USER rstudio
CMD ["/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver","--server-daemonize=0","--auth-none=1"]
```

I will caution though, the first time I did it, I ran with `sudo -E` in front of the command and it logged into RStudio as ROOT!  (this is also because I had altered the `/etc/rstudio/rserver.conf` with the setting `auth-minimum-user-id=0` because I was trying to get the error to go away (which it did :)

The above code will change to user 'rstudio' before running the command which will log you straight in as rstudio.

Hope that helps someone out there, I know I spent the better portion of my day finding a work-around!

Comment: for some reason when I follow this, the login page still shows up but I cannot login (after submitting credentials same window shows up)

Comment: @DimaLituiev how did you solve the issue? I am facing the same issue. I also want to bypass the login page

Comment: The statement

`The above code will change to user 'rstudio' before running the command which will log you straight in as rstudio.`

is no longer correct. It may have been the case when this was first posted, but it does not work now.

Comment: Need to set the environment variable `USER=rstudio` see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59506142/4413446) for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

To bypass the login page you need also to define the environment variable `USER`.

> need to set system environmental variable `USER=rstudio` in order for `--auth-none 1`
>
> -- https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1663

Here is a snippet of `Dockerfile` permitting to run the RStudio server and to login as the user `rstudio`.

```
ENV USER="rstudio"

CMD ["/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver", "--server-daemonize", "0", "--auth-none", "1"]
```

When it's run the login page is not displayed and we can check that the server and the session are running with the `rstudio` user.

```sh
# Run the container
docker run --name rstudio --rm -p 8787:8787 -d rstudio

# Check processes
docker exec -it rstudio ps aux 

USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
rstudio+     1  0.1  0.3 210792 13844 ?        Ssl  21:10   0:00 /usr/lib/rstudi
rstudio     49  0.7  2.3 555096 82312 ?        Sl   21:10   0:03 /usr/lib/rstudi
root       570  0.0  0.1  45836  3744 pts/0    Rs+  21:18   0:00 ps aux
```